# How to get whole structure from function?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char name[100];
    char number[100];
} contact_t;

void empty_array(char *line)
{
    for (int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                line[j] = '\0';     
            }
}

void read_text(contact_t *contact)
{
    int c, cnt = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char line[100];
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        if ( (c == '\n') || (c == EOF))
        {
            if( cnt % 2 == 0)
            {
                for(int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)                       
                contact -> name[j] = line[j];
            }
            else
            {
                for(int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
                contact -> number[j] = line[j];
            }
            empty_array(line);
            i = 0;
            cnt++;
        }
        line [i] = c;
        i++;
    } while (c != EOF);
}

int main()
{   
    contact_t contact = {"x", "0"};
    int *j_ptr;
     
    read_text(&contact);

    printf("%s", contact.name);    
    printf("%s", contact.number);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am reading a text file(6 lines, name and number, name and number...) from standard input. Then I assign every second line(starting from the first) from that text file to structure contact.name and the rest are I assign to contact.number. So I have several 3 contact structures. I managed to pass to main only the last one, because I don't know how to get acces to int cnt and again make a for cycle.

This is what last prints give me:

John Green
254454556

UPDATE:
I am sorry for not being clear enough as I was writing this question in a hurry. This code is a part of school project and we are not allowed to work with dynamically allocated memory or use fscanf, fopen, qsort, lsearch, bsearch and hsearch etc. Basically, I would just like to use pointers to index of array line and then in main function use a for cycle again to pass all structures from the function read_text to main function of the program.

Comment: A [mre] would help. You describing what your code does, does not.

Comment: _Side note:_ Stylistically `contact -> name` --> `contact->name` and `line [i]` --> `line[i]`

Comment: "I have several 3 contact structures". I'm pretty sure this line `contact_t contact = {"x", "0"};` declares *one* structure. You cannot read more than one structure's worth into one structure. It isn't quite clear what you are being asked to do.

Comment: I only initialized that structure in main, it does not really make a difference in output if I change it to just ``` contact_t contact```

Comment: "I only initialized that structure in main" I'm not sure what this has to do with anything. *It isn't quite clear what you are being asked to do*. What does your assignment say, *verbatim*?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I figured it out already, so no worries. Sorry for not being clear about everything I am kinda new at this.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. `main` only provides space for *one* contact entry
2. `read_text` needs to use a dynamic array (vs. overwriting the same entry)
3. `read_text` needs to return the list pointer and the count to the caller (e.g. `main`)
4. The method used in `read_text` is a bit convoluted.

Style fixes:

1. `contact -> name` --> `contact->name`
2. `list [i]` --> `list[i]`

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char number[100];
} contact_t;

int
read_text(contact_t **listp)
{
    char buf[1000];
    contact_t *list = NULL;
    char *cp = NULL;
    int cnt = 0;

    // loop on input until EOF
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) != NULL) {
        // increase size of list
        ++cnt;
        list = realloc(list,sizeof(*list) * cnt);

        // handle error
        if (list == NULL) {
            perror("realloc/increase");
            exit(1);
        }

        // point to current record
        contact_t *contact = &list[cnt - 1];

        // get first name
        contact->name[0] = 0;
        cp = strtok(buf," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcat(contact->name,cp);

        // add separater
        strcat(contact->name," ");

        // get last name
        cp = strtok(NULL," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcat(contact->name,cp);

        // get number
        cp = strtok(NULL," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcpy(contact->number,cp);
    }

    // trim to actual amount stored (if error)
    if ((cp == NULL) && (cnt > 0)) {
        --cnt;
        list = realloc(list,sizeof(*list) * cnt);
        if (list == NULL) {
            perror("realloc/trim");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // give caller the list pointer
    *listp = list;

    return cnt;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int cnt;
    contact_t *list;

    cnt = read_text(&list);

    // print all entries read in
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < cnt;  ++idx) {
        contact_t *contact = &list[idx];
        printf("'%s' '%s'\n",contact->name,contact->number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the test input I used:

```
John Green 254454556
Fred Smith 8765309
Bob Jones 99728967341
Mary Gallagher 4329268757
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
'John Green' '254454556'
'Fred Smith' '8765309'
'Bob Jones' '99728967341'
'Mary Gallagher' '4329268757'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I am sorry, I should have clarified that I cannot use dynamically allocated memory. Malloc, calloc or also fsangf is not available –
> gregalz

Okay, no `malloc` et. al. Ironically, I was going to use a predefined fixed size array. But, decided to use a dynamic array instead ;-)

Not sure what `fsangf` is. So, I'll assume that's `fscanf`. If you're heavily restricted, maybe you should *edit* your *question* and post what you *can* and can *not* use.

Here's the code that uses just a fixed array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char number[100];
} contact_t;

#define NLIST       1000
contact_t list[NLIST];

int
read_text(contact_t *list,int max)
{
    char buf[1000];
    char *cp = NULL;
    int cnt = 0;

    // loop on input until EOF
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) != NULL) {
        // don't overflow the max size
        if (cnt >= max)
            break;

        // point to current record and increase list count
        contact_t *contact = &list[cnt++];

        // get first name
        contact->name[0] = 0;
        cp = strtok(buf," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcat(contact->name,cp);

        // add separater
        strcat(contact->name," ");

        // get last name
        cp = strtok(NULL," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcat(contact->name,cp);

        // get number
        cp = strtok(NULL," \n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        strcpy(contact->number,cp);
    }

    // trim to actual amount stored (if error)
    if ((cp == NULL) && (cnt > 0))
        --cnt;

    return cnt;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int cnt;

    cnt = read_text(list,NLIST);

    // print all entries read in
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < cnt;  ++idx) {
        contact_t *contact = &list[idx];
        printf("'%s' '%s'\n",contact->name,contact->number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have clarified that I cannot use dynamically allocated memory. Malloc, calloc or also fsangf is not available

Comment: @gregalz I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, did it bit differently in the end, but you helped big time.